# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString returns true, but cannot read from a url

Tags: c#, uri

I am trying to check if the url `http://master.dev.brandgear.net` is valid by the following method:

```
private bool UrlIsValid(string url)
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                bool response;
                try
                {
                    webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    using (Stream strm = webClient.OpenRead(url))
                    {
                        response = true;
                    }
                }

                catch (WebException we)
                {
                    response = false;
                }

                return response;
            }
        }
```

However, I am getting a web exception `"404 not found."`. I have checked the uri with `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` and it is returning true. However, the same url can be opened through a browser. Any idea how to validate it?

Comment: i think you are getting error 404 not found.

Comment: yes, that's right. The question was wrongly put because of the "slash" errors.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your example with following URL http://master.dev.brandgear.net and exception is also raised. If you open same URL in browser (for example Firefox) and run Firebug plugin, open Network tab you will see error 404 (Page not found). Your code is OK, but server returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

To really get a response, you have to use WebException instead of GetResponse or GetResponseStream methods when the 404 exception happens.Also use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in these situations for better control,so after the exception occurs you check its state to see if its a ProtocolError and if so get the response from there:

```
    private bool UrlIsValid(string url)
    {
        bool response = false;
        HttpWebResponse rep = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            rep = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            if (we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                rep = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
        }

        if (rep != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream strm = rep.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    response = true;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //no need variable is already false if we didnt succeed.
                //response = false;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```